# What permission do I need to use the notifications API?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, notifications

What permissions do I need to get in order to use the notifications API? My test app contains two files:

nfytest.php:

```
<?php
require_once "../vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php";
session_start(); $_SESSION = array();

echo "<html><body>";

try{
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook(['app_id' => 'xxx','app_secret' => 'xxx', 'default_graph_version' => 'v3.2']);
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $loginurl = $helper->getLoginUrl("https://www.bkassist.com/dnamatchmakerdev/callback.php",  'email', 'publish_to_groups']);
    echo "<a href='$loginurl'>Pleaseclick on this link</a>";
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    echo 'Graph returned an error: '. $e->getMessage();
}catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException$e){
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned anerror: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
echo "</body></html>"; return 200;
```

?>

callback.php:

```
<?php
require_once "../vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php";
session_start();

ini_set("error_log", "error.log");

echo "<html><body>";

try
    {
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook(['app_id' => 'xxx', 'app_secret' => 'xxx', 'default_graph_version' => 'v3.2']);
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $at = $helper->getAccessToken();
    $fb->post("/2465651860/notifications",  ["template" => "@[2465651860] has posted something you said you were interested in", "href " => "index?nfycallback"], $at);
    echo "Success. Or at least not failure.";
    }
catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) 
    {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    } 
catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) 
    {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

echo "</body>/</html>";
return 200;
?>
```

Running this produces the error: Graph returned an error: Unsupported post request. Object with ID '2465651860' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/

I have done, but I haven't found enlightenment yet. [Sorry about the formatting of the code -- I swear I tried to make it look ok!]

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should not paste your app info in the question. So change the password to protect your app.

Then, I have do some tests, Only not give the access_token parameter will return this error. So check the the access token parameter?

BTW, This method must be called with an app access_token. and only can send notifications who has installed your app.